# How to format time

Tags: flutter, dart, format, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to format the time I get from the timePicker, but I get an error. The variable **t** (`String formatedTime = new DateFormat('HH:mm').format(t);`) is red underlined when I try to format the time and I don't know why.

This is the code I tried:

```
  pickTime() async {
    TimeOfDay t = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: pickedTime,
    );
    if (t != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickedTime = t;
        print(pickedTime.toString());
        String formatedTime = new DateFormat('HH:mm').format(t);
        print(formatedTime.toString());
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the var t in .format(t) is red underlined

Comment: what is the value of `t`? The red line is because `format()` takes an argument of type `DateTime` and not `TimeOfDay`. But the value of `t` should already be in the format `HH:mm`

Comment: But when I print the variable I get for example: TimeOfDay(18:08). How can I remove the TimeOfDay and the ()?

Comment: `print(pickedtime.hour)` this should give you the hour, or try `pickedTime.format(context)` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html

Comment: but how can I make a variable hh:mm for example 18:30?